# Moving average or sum calculation on multiple vectors in irregular time series

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a dataframe that looks like this (dput is below):

```
Date        SiteSub       HeatingDegreeDay MCnt  MCnt_lag7  MCnt_lag9
2009-11-01  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-02  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-03  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-04  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-05  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-06  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             0     0          0
2009-11-07  EC_BC.Z_Z     0.00             1     0          0
```

I am trying to calculate moving sums OR averages of width 7 for `HeatingDegreeDay`, `MCnt`, `MCnt_lag7`, `MCnt_lag9` in this dataframe. Some characteristics of this data to consider are: irregular time series with missing dates and `NA` values in the `HeatingDegreeDay` vector.

Once I have the 7-day moving sums OR averages calculated, I need to calculate correlation coefficients to help me identify which lag (7-day or 9-day) is best to match with the `HeatingDegreeDay` vector.

Question:
Can the moving sum or average calculation be combined with a correlation coefficient calculation in the same code or do they need to be done in steps? If so, how?

Problems:
In calculating the moving sums OR averages, I keep running into troubles. First, with rollapply, I cannot pass multiple vectors to `rollapply` as it seems univariate. Second, with `TTR`'s `SMA` I get an "incorrect number of dimensions" error. I can't use rollmean because my data has `NA`s.

I have looked at:
 [R: How to apply moving averages to subset of columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469432/r-how-to-apply-moving-averages-to-subset-of-columns-in-a-data-frame) and
[Conditional rolling mean (moving average) on irregular time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372735/conditional-rolling-mean-moving-average-on-irregular-time-series).

I tried:

```
#Calculate moving average 
Lag0910_79 <- as.numeric(Lag0910_79$HeatingDegreeDay, Lag0910_79$MCnt7, Lag0910_79$MCnt9)
Lagzoo <- as.zoo(Lag0910_79)
Lagzoo_7 <- rollapply(Lagzoo, width=7, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
Lagzoo_7 <- as.data.frame(Lagzoo_7)
```

with result:

```
dput(head(Lagzoo_7, 15))

structure(list(Lagzoo_7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = "Lagzoo_7", row.names = c("4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18"), class = "data.frame")`
```

and:

```
Lagzoo.ttr <- SMA(Lag0910_79[, "HeatingDegreeDay"], 7)
```

> Error in Lag0910_79[, "HeatingDegreeDay"] : 
>     incorrect number of dimensions`

How can I make this work? Clearly I don't have it right. Thanks for your help!

My data is structured like:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14549, 14550, 14551, 14552, 
14553, 14554, 14555, 14556, 14557, 14558, 14559, 14560, 14561, 
14562, 14563, 14564, 14565, 14566, 14567, 14568, 14569, 14570, 
14571, 14572, 14573, 14574, 14575, 14576, 14577, 14578, 14579, 
14580, 14581, 14582, 14583, 14584, 14585, 14586, 14587, 14588, 
14589, 14590, 14591, 14592, 14593, 14594, 14595, 14596, 14597, 
14598, 14599, 14600, 14601, 14602, 14603, 14604, 14605, 14606, 
14607, 14608, 14609, 14610, 14611, 14612, 14613, 14614, 14615, 
14616, 14617, 14618, 14619, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14621, 14622, 
14622, 14623, 14624, 14625, 14626, 14627, 14628, 14629, 14629, 
14629, 14629, 14629, 14630, 14631, 14631, 14631, 14632, 14632, 
14632, 14632, 14632, 14632, 14632, 14633, 14633, 14633, 14634, 
14634, 14634, 14634, 14635, 14635, 14635, 14635, 14636, 14636, 
14636, 14636, 14636, 14636, 14637, 14637, 14637, 14638, 14638, 
14638, 14639, 14639, 14640, 14641, 14642, 14643, 14643, 14644, 
14645, 14646, 14647, 14648, 14649, 14650, 14651, 14652, 14653, 
14654, 14655, 14656, 14657, 14658, 14659, 14660, 14661, 14661, 
14662, 14663, 14663, 14664, 14665, 14666, 14667, 14668, 14669, 
14669, 14670, 14671, 14672, 14673, 14674, 14675, 14675, 14676, 
14677, 14678, 14678, 14679, 14680, 14681, 14681, 14681, 14682, 
14682, 14682, 14683, 14684, 14685, 14686, 14687, 14688, 14689, 
14689, 14690, 14691, 14692, 14693, 14694, 14694, 14694, 14695, 
14696, 14697, 14698, 14699, 14700, 14701, 14702, 14703, 14703, 
14703, 14703, 14704, 14704, 14705, 14706), class = "Date"), SiteSub = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "EC_BC.Z_Z", class = "factor"), 
    HeatingDegreeDay = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 
    14L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
    6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0.00", 
    "0.02", "0.05", "0.14", "0.32", "0.50", "0.89", "0.96", "0.98", 
    "1.02", "1.04", "1.30", "1.40", "1.49", "1.50", "1.58", "1.86"
    ), class = "factor"), MCnt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    MCnt_lag7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    MCnt_lag9 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"SiteSub", "HeatingDegreeDay", "MCnt", "MCnt_lag7", "MCnt_lag9"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
"65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
"76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", 
"87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", 
"98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
"107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
"116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
"125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
"134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
"143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", 
"152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
"161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", 
"170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
"179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", 
"188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
"197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", 
"206", "207", "208"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134823/r-faster-way-to-calculate-rolling-statistics-over-a-variable-interval, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571788/regular-analysis-over-irregular-time-series?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960352/optimized-rolling-functions-on-irregular-time-series-with-time-based-window?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465998/sliding-time-intervals-for-time-series-data-in-r

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate why this was downvoted? I provided all the criteria to ask a question. I researched this topic for two days and found nothing that worked.

Comment: I downvoted because I couldn't understand what your question was. I should have commented why. Recommendations: Can you simplify your example data set to make things easier to understand? Can you provide an example of what you would like your final output to be?

Comment: @Kevin, thank you for elaborating. I am trying to calculate a 7-day average for four columns within my dataframe by Date without having to do each column individually. The data I provided is already extremely simplified and I will work on what an output would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data frame shown in the `dput` output of the question is `DF` then this converts columns 3:6 to numeric, performs the rollmean calculation producing `rmean`, a matrix of rolling means.  It then uses `corNA` to produce a vector, `rcor`, of rolling correlations and puts everything into one data frame, `DF3`:

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- DF
DF2[3:6] <- lapply(DF2[3:6], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
m <- as.matrix(DF2[3:6])
rmean <- rollapplyr(m, 7, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA) # mean matrix

corNA <- function(x) {
    x <- na.omit(x[, 1:2])
    if (nrow(x) < 2 || sd(x[,1]) == 0 || sd(x[,2]) == 0) return(NA)
    cor(x[, 1], x[,2])
}

rcor <- rollapplyr(m, 7, corNA, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA) # vector of cors

DF3 <- data.frame(DF2, rmean, rcor) # put it all together
```

The zoo version is here.  Since zoo requires unique dates we aggregate rows with equal dates:

```
z <- read.zoo(DF2[-2], aggregate = mean) # can omit aggregate=mean if dates are unique

zmean <- rollapplyr(z, 7, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA) # means
zcor <- rollapplyr(z, 7, corNA, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA) # cors

z2 <- merge(z, zmean, zcor) # omit this if separate objects are ok
```

Comment: thank you for pointing to my error in including information about the independent/dependent variables. I had been working on slopes and linear model stuffs. I included it in here by accident. For clarification, I do just want a moving correlation.

Comment: I get the following errors:
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

> zm <- rollapplyr(z, 7, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in merge.zoo(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: Sorry, there was some junk at the end of the `cor` line but removing that it runs without any warnings or errors on the dput data.frame provided in the question. I have shown a log of the result at the end.

Comment: there are "NA" values in the HeatingDegreeDay field, which is the third column in the original dataframe. Could this be the reason for the errors? I'm still getting errors with: 

DF2 <- Lag0910_79
DF2[3:6] <- lapply(DF2[3:6], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
z <- read.zoo(DF2[-2])
zm <- rollapplyr(z, 7, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Cut it down to a small reproducible example.  It does not happen with the data provided in the question.

Comment: I edited my question to include only the entire dataframe. I need the NA values to remain in the dataframe. How can I make your code run with the NA values?

Comment: Not clear what "the NA values to remain" means but I have revised the code so that it runs with the new input shown.  The new thing introduced by it was duplicate dates, not supported by zoo so matrices used instead now.

Comment: After looking at your code, I think I understand what it does. I'm new to using R. I've never used a matrix before, only dataframes. If I got rid of the duplicate dates in my data, would the as.matrix still work? Also, I understand that rollapplyr is the same as "align=right." If I wanted to have align=center, do I just remove the "r" so it would be rollapply?

Comment: (1) The code works with or without duplicates. If you did not have duplicates then one could go back to the zoo formulation which would be slightly slicker. (2) Yes, remove `r` if you want centered rolling as that is the default.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I've never understood how to write functions. I think I understand how it works. If I wanted to add some code that also calculates coefficients for cor(x[,1], x[,3] and cor(x[,1], x[,4] where in the function would I put these? I would like the function to calculate cofficients for column 1/column 2; column1/column3; column1/column4. 

If I wanted to switch back to using zoo formulation, do I change as.matrix to as.zoo?

Comment: Omitting the checks `function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, -1])` calculates the correlation of column 1 with each of the other columns.  With that be sure you use `by.column = FALSE` in `rollapply`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by "Omitting the checks function(x) cor(x[,1], x[,-1])."

Comment: do I delete something from the function? I changed the 2 to a 4 in the na.omit: `x <- na.omit(x[, 1:4])` and it returned three columns of coefficients.

Comment: This change to the function didn't give me the coefficients for all data available though.

Comment: `function(x) cor(x[,1], x[,-1])` is a replacement for `corNA` except it does not include the checks for NA, sd=0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted for the rolling mean?

```
# Convert dates to days
aa = as.Date(x$Date)
x$Date = as.numeric(aa - aa[1])

# I think it's easier to get rid of the factors
factor2number = function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
x[,3:6] = apply(x[,3:6],2,factor2number)

# A rolling mean function
rollmean_r = function(x,y,width) {
  out = numeric(length(x))
  for( i in seq_along(x) ) {
    window = x >= (x[i]-width) & x <= (x[i]+width)
    out[i] = .Internal(mean( y[window] ))
  }
  return(out)
}

# Calculate the rolling means
x[,3:6] = apply(x[3:6], 2, function(y) rollmean_r(x$Date,y,7) )
x
#    Date   SiteSub HeatingDegreeDay       MCnt MCnt_lag7  MCnt_lag9
# 1     0 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.12500000         0         0
# 2     1 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.11111111         0         0
# 3     2 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.10000000         0         0
# 4     3 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.09090909         0         0
# 5     4 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.08333333         0         0
# 6     5 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.07692308         0         0
# 7     6 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.07142857         0         0
# 8     7 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.06666667         0         0
# 9     8 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.07142857         0         0
# 10    9 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.07692308         0         0
# 11   10 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.08333333         0         0
# 12   11 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.09090909         0         0
# 13   12 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.10000000         0         0
# 14   13 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.11111111         0         0
# 15   14 EC_BC.Z_Z                0 0.00000000         0         0
```